# Entity Framework : boolean value is true

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, crud, swagger-ui

How can I set the default value of a boolean to false in Entity Framework in .NET Core.

Thank you

```
public class CategoryVM
{
    public CategoryVM()
    {
        isOpen = false;

        Products = new List<ProductVM>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile? ImageFile { get; set; }

    public string? catImeage { get; set; }
    public Boolean isOpen { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<ProductVM> Products { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Boolean properties default to false by default in C#. The json you see in swagger is just an example of the values you can pass in the request body (like it says right above the json).

Answer (score 0):

Try `public Boolean isOpen { get; set; } = true; //true or false default`

or in migration

```
public override void Up()
{    
  AddColumn("dbo.TABLE", "isOpen", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false, 
   defaultValue: true));
}
```

Comment: This did not work - public Boolean isOpen { get; set; } = true;